# draw one or more plots in the same window

Tags: r, plot

I want compare two curves, it's possible with R to draw a plot and then draw another plot over it ? how ?

thanks.

Comment: If you want more examples, you should take a look at R graph library (http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/) it is a good source of inspiration as the code and the results are there.

Answer (score 5):

With base R, you can plot your one curve and then add the second curve with the `lines()` argument. Here's a quick example:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- x^2
y2 <- x^3

plot(x,y, type = "l")
lines(x, y2, col = "red")
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to use ggplot2, here are two methods - one plots different colors on the same plot, and the other generates separate plots for each variable. The trick here is to "melt" the data into long format first.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x, y, y2)

df.m <- melt(df, id.var = "x")

qplot(x, value, data = df.m, colour = variable, geom = "line")

qplot(x, value, data = df.m, geom = "line")+ facet_wrap(~ variable)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [lattice package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=lattice):

```
require(lattice)
x <- seq(-3,3,length.out=101)
xyplot(dnorm(x) + sin(x) + cos(x) ~ x, type = "l")
```

[image: Lattice curve plot]

Answer (score 2):

There's been some solutions already for you. If you stay with the base package, you should get acquainted with the functions `plot(), lines(), abline(), points(), polygon(), segments(), rect(), box(), arrows(), ...`Take a look at their help files.

You should see a plot from the base package as a pane with the coordinates you gave it. On that pane, you can draw a whole set of objects with the abovementioned functions. They allow you to construct a graph as you want. You should remember though that, unless you play with the par settings like Dr. G showed, every call to plot() gives you a new pane. Also take into account that things can be plot over other things, so think about the order you use to plot things.

See eg:

```
set.seed(100)
x <- 1:10
y <- x^2
y2 <- x^3
yse <- abs(runif(10,2,4))

plot(x,y, type = "n")  # type="n" only plots the pane, no curves or points.

# plots the area between both curves
polygon(c(x,sort(x,decreasing=T)),c(y,sort(y2,decreasing=T)),col="grey")
# plot both curves
lines(x,y,col="purple")
lines(x, y2, col = "red")
# add the points to the first curve
points(x, y, col = "black")
# adds some lines indicating the standard error
segments(x,y,x,y+yse,col="blue")
# adds some flags indicating the standard error
arrows(x,y,x,y-yse,angle=90,length=0.1,col="darkgreen")
```

This gives you :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at par

```
> ?par
> plot(rnorm(100))
> par(new=T)
> plot(rnorm(100), col="red")
```

Answer (score 1):

ggplot2 is a great package for this sort of thing:

```
install.packages('ggplot2')
require(ggplot2)
x <- 1:10
y1 <- x^2
y2 <- x^3
df <- data.frame(x = x, curve1 = y1, curve2 = y2)
df.m <- melt(df, id.vars = 'x', variable_name = 'curve' )
# now df.m is a data frame with columns 'x', 'curve', 'value'
ggplot(df.m, aes(x,value)) + geom_line(aes(colour = curve)) + 
geom_point(aes(shape=curve))
```

You get the plot coloured by curve, and with different piont marks for each curve, and a nice legend, all painlessly without any additional work:

[image]

Comment: your code does not run in it's current form. You are missing a parens after the initial call to `ggplot` and are referencing the wrong object. Here is a working version: `
ggplot(df.m, aes(x,value)) + geom_line(aes(colour = curve)) + 
geom_point(aes(shape=curve))'

Comment: Thanks Chase, and apologies for the sloppiness.

Answer (score 0):

Draw multiple curves at the same time with the matplot function. Do help(matplot) for more.